# How to add class by existing class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class **active** for the div having class **in** (contained in div with class shiftTabs).

I used below jQuery but not working.

```
$('.shiftTabs .tab-pane[class="in"]').not('.active').addClass('active');
```

**Html:-**

```
 <div class="shiftTabs">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab1" tabindex="1">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2" tabindex="2">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3" tabindex="3">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add extra class to active element. You can use `in` class and add properties on it.

Comment: i want to add in particular class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain the class selector instead of using attribute equals selector:

```
$('.shiftTabs .tab-pane.in:not(.active)').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just use the selector `$('.shiftTabs .tab-pane.in').not('.active')`

```js
$('.shiftTabs .tab-pane.in').not('.active').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shiftTabs">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab1" tabindex="1">123</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2" tabindex="2">123</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3" tabindex="3">123</div>
</div>
```